# Getting error code 204 on App engine PHP + BigQuery

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm getting this error:

```
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. 
This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. 
(Error code 204)
```

I have a PHP app that is mostly using BigQuery. It's very frustrating that I have no way to debug this.

Nothing [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9786) helped me.

What can I do?

app id is: `logolapp`

**Update** answers to questions from replies

1. yes, it's still occurring, not every requests, but something like 1/20 requests. It has happened since I started working on this app, which was about a week ago.
2. in the logs. in the browser i'm just getting 500
3. it happens randomly for 1/20 requests or so
4. i'm putting and querying statistical information in BigQuery.

**Another update - my app.yaml:**

```
application: logolapp
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /data
  script: data.php

- url: /get/.*
  script: get.php

- url: /query/.*
  script: query.php

- url: /post
  script: post.php

- url: /postidm
  script: main.php

- url: /info
  script: info.php
```

Comment: Could you please also publish your app.yaml file?

Comment: @DoITInternational added app.yaml

Comment: Can you please try to redeploy the application with the ```threadsafe``` value set to ```false```, as this may be related to the cause of your issue. Also, please let me know whether you are using Memcache extensively within your application.

Comment: @DoITInternational made the change. so far didn't hit the error, so it looks like it's working. But won't it degrade performance considerably?

Comment: I am unaware of threadsafe set to false degrading performance. Threadsafe setting to true would actually slow down the application because you are purposefully making sure requests are handled more or less sequentially to avoid data contention.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include changing the ***threadsafe*** to ```false``` suggestion. Since it solved your problem, please mark my answer as "accepted". [This is why it's important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible causes for this issue, one of which is a lack of memory on the instance, which could be resolved by moving memory-intensive processes to a backend instance with more memory, or increasing the instance class of the instances you are using now.

Another possible cause could be a scaling issue. I would need to see the scaling settings in your app.yaml to confirm that, however.

**Finally, it might be related to the `threadsafe` being set to `true` in your `app.yaml`.Please set the `threadsafe` to `false` to make sure GAE is not messing with your code**

It would be helpful if you could revise your question and add this information:

- Is the issue still occurring for you? When did the issue start?
- Is the error showing up in your logs or is it when you attempt to access the application via the browser?
- Is the issue happening continuously or in batches? If in batches, how often does it occur?
- What are you attempting to do with BigQuery?